# How to rotate a CAShapeLayer at its center point

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, calayer, cashapelayer

I have made a `CAShapeLayer` with few points by setting its stroke color to red . Then i have filled the color with a pattern of an `UIImage`. I want to rotate that `CAShapeLayer` along with its filled pattern using `UIRotationGestureRecognizer`.

I have used CATransform3DRotate but it is not working properly.

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, recognizer.rotation, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
shapeLayer.transform = transform;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8232192/1161906)

Answer (score 9):

You'll want to call:

```
shapeLayer.anchorPoint = (CGPoint){0.5, 0.5};
```

You're also starting with the identity transform, which throws away any transformations you've done before, like positioning the layer. What you want to do is:

```
shapeLayer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(shapeLayer.transform, recognizer.rotation, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: I have used this. But whole CAShapeLayer is rotating around the center of the UIImageView at the background.

Comment: @HiteshBhardwaj in that case I'm guessing that the shape layer doesn't have it's bounds set